# Spring MVC - Uploading File Status 400 - Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present

Tags: spring, file, maven, netbeans, upload

I'm new in Spring. I have excercise to make a Web app where the file is uploaded and then written to database. I'm making it with Spring MVC and Maven in Netbeans.

I made a fully working basic project based on this tutorial

https://saarapakarinen.wordpress.com/2015/01/11/building-a-basic-spring-3-web-project-netbeans-and-maven/

And tried to expand it for my application, wanted to make file uploading component based of official Spring tutorial

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multipart

but its not working, got an error:

HTTP Status 400 - Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present

I've expanded this project with wyslij.jsp (form for upload file)

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Wysylanie pliku</title>
    </head>

<body>
    <form method="get" action="http://localhost:8084/Hello/application/wyslij" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="file"/>
            <input type="submit"/>
        </form>
</body>


</html>
```

And  added Controller for uplading file called UpladController.java

```
package helloweb;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

@Controller
public class UploadController 
{

    @RequestMapping(value = "wyslij", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String handleFormUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException 
    {

        if (!file.isEmpty()) {
            byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
            // store the bytes somewhere
           return "redirect:tak";
       } else 
        {
           return "redirect:nie";
       }
    }

}
```

web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee                               http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <!-- name of the project//-->
    <display-name>HelloProject</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>front-controller</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>front-controller</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/application/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- max time of the session //-->

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <!-- default page //-->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>application/wyslij.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

and front-controller-serlvet.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

     <!-- configuration to fetch jsp files automatically from WEB-INF/jsp -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"> 
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" /> 
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" /> 
    </bean>

    <bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">

    <!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000"/>

</bean>



    <context:component-scan base-package="helloweb" />

</beans>
```

Could someone tell, why is an error and explain?

EDIT:

I decided to use form.jsp and HelloController.java made in tutorial and convert it to file upload (they were working more than my code)

form.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

        <title>Form Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>

            <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://localhost:8084/Hello/application/form">
              <label>file to send: <input type="file" name="file" /></label>
              <input type="submit" />
            </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

and HelloController.java

```
package helloweb;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;


@Controller
public class HelloController 
{ 
    @RequestMapping(value = "form", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String login(@RequestParam(value = "file", required = true) MultipartFile file) throws IOException 
    {
                    if (!file.isEmpty()) 
                    {
            byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
            // store the bytes somewhere
           return "redirect:tak";
       } 
                    else 
        {
           return "redirect:nie";
        }

    }

        @RequestMapping("form")
    public String viewLoginPage(Model model)
    {  
        return "form";
    }
}
```

Now I have at least file upload form displayed properly at start page, but after  selecting a file and click button, I get antoher error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to process parts as no multi-part configuration has been provided
```

Answer (score 1):

Chnaged and Controller now is:

```
@Controller
public class UploadController 
{

    @RequestMapping(value = "wyslij", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String handleFormUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException 
    {

        if (!file.isEmpty()) {
            byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
            // store the bytes somewhere
           return "redirect:tak";
       } else 
        {
           return "redirect:nie";
       }
    }

}
```

and the jsp:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Wysylanie pliku</title>
    </head>

<body>
    <form method="post" action="http://localhost:8084/Hello/application/wyslij" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="file"/>
            <input type="submit"/>
        </form>
</body>


</html>
```

tested service with postman
result for GET test:

```
HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'GET' not supported

type Status report

message Request method 'GET' not supported

description The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource.
```

result for POST test:

```
HTTP Status 400 - Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present

type Status report

message Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present

description The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sending file with multipart/form data encoding which needs Http POST. In your controller change it to post like below.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "wyslij", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

And in your jsp as well.

```
 <form method="post" action="http://localhost:8084/Hello/application/wyslij" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file"/>
        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
```

Comment: I was trying to change it too. When methods changed to POST i get another error: HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'GET' not supported. Strange because I'm using POST method, not GET.

Comment: Did you change it to "post" both in controller and jsp? Can you please test your service using soapui or Postman.

Comment: for  Posman POST request add header with key=file and value=multipart/form-data. In Body tab select form-data and key=file and then choosefile button to upload file. And then Send request

Comment: Strange, done as You said and got error HTTP Status 404 - /Hello/application/wyslij

type Status report

message /Hello/application/wyslij

description The requested resource is not available.

Comment: You are using return "redirect:nie"; which needs GET mapping. Add one more method in Controller to handle redirected GET request. Something like @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/nie", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public  @ResponseBody String finalPage() {      
       return "final";
    }

Comment: I made major change in code and files now. Instead of adding my files, I edited the ones made in tutorial to form with file upload instead of text, see Edit in main post.